# How to retrieve pageContext in SPFx?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework

I'm following the second tutorial from the SharePoint Framework dev center:

[Connect to SharePoint](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint)

It states that you can retrieve details from `this.context.pageContext`, however this is no longer the case with the GA (1.0.0) release as the codebase has changed, and the documentation and tutorials haven't been updated to reflect this. The documentation seems to point to either IWebPartContext, or PageContext, but I'm just a little lost on how exactly to retrieve the page context from the component (webparts\helloWorld\components\HelloWorld.tsx).

Could someone shed some light on the new method for going about this?

Comment: The code samples are still out of date (9 months later).  I've created an issue for it:  https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1257.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`this.context.pageContext` is available on `render()` method within top level class that extends `BaseClientSideWebPart`.
Simply pass `this.context` as a props of to HelloWorld.tsx to reuse it.

Sample (HelloWorldWebpart.ts):

```
public render(): void {
const element: React.ReactElement<any > = React.createElement(
   HelloWorld,
   {
     description: this.properties.description,
     context: this.context
   }
);

 ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}
```

And in HelloWorld.tsx you should be able to retrieve the context as `this.props.context`

Or alternatively use react redux to store the context on initialization `onInit()` method (https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/reference/spfx/sp-webpart-base/oninit-baseclientsidewebpart)

Comment: Thank you! This is all I was looking for. To any one else that stumbles on this: I was able to get this working by simply adding `context: any;` to my component props file and passing it as Jonathan mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

It is better to use correct type **WebPartContext** instead of **any**. Don't forget to put namespace.

```
import { WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

export interface WebPartProps {
   context: WebPartContext;
   description: string;
}
...

public render(): void {
   const element: React.ReactElement<WebPartProps> = React.createElement(
   HelloWorld,
   {
     description: this.properties.description,
     context: this.context
   }
);

 ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}
```

Here is more info [WebPartContext class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-webpart-base/webpartcontext?view=sp-typescript-latest)

Comment: Sadly, WebPartContext is depreciated as of 10/2022.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of passing pageContext to React component:

Add property to component interface. Note that I import PageContent declaration for nice IntelliSence pop-ups (I use VS Code)

```
    import { PageContext } from '@microsoft/sp-page-context'; // load page context declaration
    export interface IHelloWorldProps {
      description: string;
      pageContext: PageContext;// here we passing page context
    }
```

Then I pass pageContect from Render method of SPFx web part:

```
      public render(): void {
        const element: React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> = React.createElement(
          HelloWorld,
          {
            description: this.properties.description,
            pageContext: this.context.pageContext
          }
        );

        ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
      }
```

And part of code from the React component itself:

```
    <p>Loading from {escape(this.props.pageContext.web.title)}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For legacy context this works:

```
public render(): void {
  // copy context up to the window
  (<any>window).myContext = this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext; 
....
```

usage out in js land:

```
let relUrl = window.myContext["webAbsoluteUrl"];
//window.webPartContext.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl;
```