# SPFX webpart context is undefined

Tags: spfx-webparts, reactjs

Ok so i've searched for a while and tried everything. I've followed these steps as well -> [How to retrieve pageContext in SPFx?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211810/how-to-retrieve-pagecontext-in-spfx)

So far its just a "testing phase", but i get stuck at the beginning since i cant get to the SP context.

This is what i've tried for testing ->

```
{escape(this.context.pageContext.web.title)}
```

And i'm getting "cant get property web of undefined".

Any idea?

Comment: Where is this code? I see you tagged this with react. Is this code in your main webpart class or in a react component?

Comment: The code that i posted in my question is located in the main webpart TSX. To be more exact its where you edit how the webpart looks. By default it contains 

    return (
      <div className={ styles.WEBPARTNAME}>

Hopefully you can understand from my "amazing" explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Old reply, but someone is bound to run into the same error.

When you're passing the context as a prop in the base WebPart, make sure you're passing it by using the this.context.

Passing the WebPartContext prop **from** the base web part component **to** the child component:

```
export default class SpTestAppWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart {

  public render() {
    const element = React.createElement(
      SpTestApp,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        ctx: this.context
      }
    );
  }
```

Then inside the child component, you should be able to use the WebPartContext on the props passed to it:

```
export default class SpTestApp extends React.Component {

  public render() {
    return (
      <div className={ styles.spTestApp }>
        <div className={ styles.container }>
            <p>{this.props.ctx.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}</p>          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the TSX then you're in the component, not the web part. A component is a dumb rendering construct. All your logic should be dealt with inside the web part itself, passing data to the component.

I don't like the way the SPFX tooling puts components in the same folder as web parts. It exacerbates misunderstandings like this. A much better architecture in my opinion would be to have a separate top level components folder.

Comment: I am already passing the context to the Component through props (same as the default description prop). However...it says its undefined. So there is either a bug with React SPFX or i'm not passing the context correctly (tho i get no compilation errors or whatever).