# SPFx: Can you use WebPartContext in components different than the main one?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, microsoft-graph

I am trying to call Microsoft Graph from a component, different than the main one. 
As a first step I am declaring a variable for the MSGraphClient's serviceKey like this:

```
const graphClient: MSGraphClient = this.props.context.serviceScope.consume(MSGraphClient.serviceKey);
```

If I declare this variable within the main component, i.e. the one, initially rendered by the `DefaultWebPart.ts` file, then I'm able to make calls to the Microsoft Graph;

However, it's enough that I declare that variable on a component, different than the main one (I'm still importing the context like that: `import { WebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base")`, but start getting the error message

> 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'serviceScope' of undefined'

as soon as the variable has been declared.

Answer (score 4):

Are you passing the `context` down as part of `props`?

According to [this other answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/211816/8992), `this.context.pageContext` is only available in the top level class/component that inherits from `BaseClientSideWebPart`, and in order to have it available in other lower level components, you need to pass the `context` down as part of `props`.

(Also see the other answer to that question that recommends strongly typing the `context` prop as `WebPartContext` instead of `any`.  Good point, I think.)

Answer (score 4):

You can pass it through the props:

In your other component define props interface:

```
export interface IProps {
  description: string;
  ctx: WebPartContext;
}
```

Declare your second component as

```
    export class MyComp extends React.Component<IProps,{}> { ....
```

In your "main" web part use:

```
const element: React.ReactElement<IProps> = React.createElement(
      MyComp,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        ctx: this.context
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
```

In your new component, you can access context via `this.props.ctx`

Comment: hello Sergei,

Thank you for your input.

The component 'MyComp' is in this case the app's main component.
What I'm interested in is accessing the context within a child component of MyComp, in this case.

Comment: @LachezarStefanov you cannot get the context directly from your child component. You have to pass it from .ts file (Base) to your Main Component. Then you can use it or pass it to your child components through props.

Comment: `MyComp` in my example is a child component. In this component you can access context via `this.props.ctx`.