# Add document set content type to a library using Rect and SPFX SharePoint Online modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, document-set, modern-experience

I am trying to add document set content type from site collection to a library, but I am failing to do that.

Please help me to solve this issue. I am trying to use React and SPFx for SharePoint Online Modern site.

```
AddContentTypeToList=()=>
  {
    let ctEndpointUrl = `${this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.list}')/ContentTypes/AddAvailableContentType`;
    let listUrl = `${this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/${this.props.list}`;
    let options : ISPHttpClientOptions= { 
      method: "POST", 
      
      body: JSON.stringify(
        { 'Title' : "Test New CT" , 'Path' : listUrl }),
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 
          'odata-version': '',
           type: "POST",
           data: JSON.stringify({  
            "contentTypeId": "0x0120D52000B6B95AFB1E9F5444905DA0AFE9C8F2CF0014BD370B726AB045A140BBF6DA440933"
            }) 
        }
      };
    
      this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(listUrl,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, options).then((d:SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        d.json().then(res => {
          // success
          alert("CT Created");
          console.log(res);
        })                
      }).catch(e => {
        // error
        console.log(e);
      });
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. maybe the current code you are using/trying to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for reply bro, updated  the code.

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console while running this code?

Comment: yes bro, Error making HttpClient request in queryable [404]

Comment: Try to check the complete error **message** in console or network tab. You must be passing wrong library name or field names or content type ID.

Comment: Error: unable to determine web url

Comment: That means you are passing wrong web URL. check what you are getting in `ctEndpointUrl` and `listUrl` by logging it to console or by adding breakpoint in your code.

Comment: Bro, I updated the url, now  it  is not throwing any error but also not creating content type

Comment: I think there is problem in your webpart context? are you passing the webpart context from main webpart file to your react component as a prop?

Comment: I am hardcoding  now, but  still not working bro:
https://mysan.sp.com/sites/MyDevSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test3')/ContentTypes/AddAvailableContentType"

Comment: Yes, I understand. the issue of web url is resolved using this. but now the issue is you are not getting `spHttpClient` in your code. as you are not able to get it from context

Answer (score 0):

Try my test code,this works well in my environment.Remember to change the contentTypeId.

```
update() {

    const requestHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
    requestHeaders.append('Content-type', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
    requestHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');


    const body: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        'contentTypeId': "0x0120D520"

      }),
      headers: requestHeaders
    };
    this.context.spHttpClient.post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Doc')/contenttypes/AddAvailableContentType`,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, body)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {
          console.log(responseJSON);
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I tried the above code, I  am facing issue like this: @Amos_MSFT
sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_d342d4b5e6f80229d85d049dc5a8e181.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Comment: You could try to console.log(this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl) to check if the url is right.

Comment: https://mysan.sp.com/sites/MySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test3')/ContentTypes/AddAvailableContentType
I am directly giving this in url, but still I am facing same issue

Comment: If you configure custom context,change this.context.spHttpClient.post to this.props.context.spHttpClient.post

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the webpart context in your react component. First of all you need to pass the webpart context from your main webpart file to react component like below:

```
public render(): void {
   const element: React.ReactElement<any > = React.createElement(
     HelloWorld,
     {
        description: this.properties.description,
        context: this.context
     }
   );

   ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}
```

Then you can use it in your react component file like:

```
let webUrl = this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl
```

Reference: [How to retrieve pageContext in SPFx?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211810/how-to-retrieve-pagecontext-in-spfx)

Once you get the SPFx context and `spHttpClient` correctly then you can add the content type to your library. For that follow the code given in above answer by Amos or below article:

[SharePoint Online: Add Content Type to List using Rest API](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37594.sharepoint-online-add-content-type-to-list-using-rest-api.aspx) - Make sure to replace the name of library and content type ID.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code, Below code is the

```
private AddContentTypeToList = () => {
  let ctEndpointUrl = `${this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${this.props.list}')/ContentTypes/AddAvailableContentType`;
  let options: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
     headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
        'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
        "contentTypeId": "0x0120D520"
     })
  };

  this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(ctEndpointUrl,
     SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, options)
     .then((d: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        d.json().then(res => {
           alert("CT Created");
           console.log(res);
        });
     }).catch(e => {
        // error
        console.log(e);
     });
```

}